# How to write test class for the account update trigger

Tags: triggers, salesforce

Iam trying to create the testclass for the apex trigger for the account update trigger
here iam attesting my code which i have written for the helperclass (trigger)
public with sharing class AccountTiggerHelper{

```
public static void UpdateOpportunityLeadSourceThroughAccount(List<Account> accNewList, Map<Id, Account> oldMapObject){

    // Variable decalration
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
    List<Opportunity> updateOpportunity = new List<Opportunity>();


    //Get account details
    for (Account acc : accNewList){
        Account old = oldMapObject.get(acc.Id);
        if ((acc.Account_Sub_Source__c != old.Account_Sub_Source__c) || (acc.AccountSource != old.AccountSource)){
            accountIds.add(acc.Id);
            accountMap.put(acc.Id, acc);
        }
    }

    if (!accountIds.isEmpty()){

        //Get opportunity according to account id
        for (Opportunity opp : [select Id, Name, Lead_Sub_Source__c, LeadSource, AccountId
                                from Opportunity
                                where AccountId in :accountIds]){
            Account acc = accountMap.get(opp.AccountId);
            opp.Lead_Sub_Source__c = acc.Account_Sub_Source__c;
            opp.LeadSource = acc.AccountSource;
            updateOpportunity.add(opp);
        }


        //Update opportunity
        if (updateOpportunity.size() > 0){
            try{
                update updateOpportunity;
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.debug(e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried, what's your unit test so far (even if it doesn't compile), what are you stuck at?

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to create an Account in a separated method inside the testClass in a method called "makeData" for exemple.

After, you'll need to query for this Account in an another test method and so, update the **Account_Sub_Source__c** and **AccountSource** fields of this Account.

I make an example test for you, so you also will need to create another test method for bulking operation.

```
@isTest
private static testUpdateAccount(){
    Accounte acc = [SELECT Id, Account_Sub_Source__c, AccountSource FROM Account LIMIT 1];
    Test.startTest();

    //Change the value of Account_Sub_Source__c and AccountSource here
    acc.Account_Sub_Source__c = 'New value';
    acc.AccountSource = 'New value';
    Update acc;

    Test.stopTest();
}
```